# Sculpt mode mirroring

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I have been having some trouble with my sculpting. Whenever I sculpt something, it does not mirror to the other side. But, in my tutorial. Micheal's model gets mirrored to the other side. Please help me, and other users who might be having the same problem solve this.

Here is a Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @MrZak yep it is

Comment: Is the rotation applied? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ctrl+A > Rotation. See manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sculpting strokes are mirrored according to the local coordinates of the object. From [manual about sculpting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html#symmetry-lock-panel):

> **Mirror**
>       Mirror the brush strokes across the selected local axes. Note that if you want to alter the directions the axes point in, you must rotate the model in Edit Mode, not Object Mode

Hence if you rotated model in Object mode make sure to [apply rotation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply) (same effect as rotating in Edit mode, i.e. making changes to mesh data).

Otherwise the strokes might be mirrored not as expected (mirrored by X axis instead of Y axis or the other way around and so on). It's likely that strokes were mirrored on your mesh, but not where you were searching for them; e.g. if you rotated object 90 degrees by Z axis and enabled mirroring by Y axis, strokes will be mirrored along X axis instead.